# Query to include what doesn't exist in checkout table AND exclude what hasn't been checked in

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables 'tools' and 'checkinout' with the following data (I've left out the irrelevant columns):

```
**tools**
id
---------
1
2
3
4
5

**checkinout**
CheckOutDT     CheckInDT     idTool
------------------------------------
2013-11-01     2013-11-02    1
2013-11-01     2013-11-02    2
2013-11-02     NULL          2
2013-11-03     NULL          4
```

tool.id is checkinout.idTool

I need my query to return the results as such

```
tool_query
id
--------
1
3
5
```

I've tried several queries but no luck.  This is my original attempt, which works perfectly if I only have one tool currently checked out but more than one breaks the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tools.id, tools.ToolNumber, tools.Description 
FROM tools, checkinout 
WHERE tools.id<>(
  SELECT checkinout.idTool 
  FROM checkinout 
  WHERE checkinout.CheckInDT Is Null)
```

All my other attempts haven't been any better than this.  I'd appreciate any help with this.  I've been fighting this for the past 4.5 hours now.

Comment: When you want to compare a value to a list, you use `IN` and `NOT IN`, not `=` and `<>`.

Comment: LOL, that did it!!! Replacing the <> with NOT IN got me exactly what I needed.  Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.id
FROM tools t
LEFT JOIN checkinout c ON t.id = c.idTool AND c.CheckInDT IS NULL
WHERE c.idTool IS NULL
```

[FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3994c8/4)

Comment: Turns out, this was the more correct answer for me.  While testing, I had entries in the checkinout table and everything worked fine.  When I put this into production the checkinout table was empty and using the NOT IN segment caused null results on my tool list.  Barmar's answer fixed that for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is quite close.  You just don't need the extra table in the `from` clause, and you need to phrase the `where` clause correctly:

```
SELECT tools.id, tools.ToolNumber, tools.Description 
FROM tools
WHERE tools.id not in (SELECT checkinout.idTool 
                       FROM checkinout 
                       WHERE checkinout.CheckInDT Is Null
                      )
```